# Concatenate fields in a view with comma when values may be empty

Tags: views

[One can easily concatenate fields in views with a re-write rule.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32277/how-can-i-concatenate-two-fields-in-a-view). However, I have two fields, `age_range` and `warning`, the second of which may be empty. I want to display them like this:

> Ages 2+
>
> Ages 4-10, choking hazard

If `warning` is empty, I don't want to show a comma. If I make a rewrite rule like this

```
[age_range], [warning]
```

Then I get a result like this:

> Ages 2+,
>
> Ages 4-10, choking hazard

How can I avoid a trailing comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually suggest doing the reverse of the answered question that you linked to for just the scenario you are describing.

1. Add Field B and Exclude it from the display.
2. In the Rewrite results area of Field B, enable Rewrite the output of this field.
3. On Field B, add a comma and the token for the raw value: ', [field-b]'
4. Under 'No Results Behavior' for Field B, make sure that 'Hide if empty' and 'Hide rewriting if empty' are checked.
5. Then rewrite your Field A to include Field B: '[field-a][field-b]'. Make sure there is no space, so that the comma will immediately follow Field A if Field B has a value.